# Google Chrome Dev Tools remove element's :after from DOM when :after display is none

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pseudo-element, css-content

My problem is about Google Chrome Dev Tools when I want to set `display: none;` to an after in DOM for a moment but Chrome remove all afters elements from DOM and I can't access to them again.
My Chrome version is the last.
Is there any solution in Google Chrome Dev Tools setting for this issue?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: be more specific and target only the needed after element

Comment: maybe try to use `opacity:0`

Comment: Dont think there is any solution to this, as pseudo elements are created by css, therefor once you tell them to stop existing (like display: none) they have no place to stay so they vanish.

Comment: @Temani Afif: That's exactly what they're doing, choosing a specific pseudo-element and switching it off. This does modify an existing ::after rule instead of creating a new one, though.

Comment: Is this reasonable? I was working with the Firebug before and I haven't this issue. now in new versions of Firefox Dev tools I have seen the same problem.

Comment: @BoltClock I understand that *all the afters elements* are disappearing when setting display:none to only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be an option to disable this behavior, but a workaround is to select the originating element to which the `::after` you were switching off was attached and you'll find its `::after` pseudo-element CSS rule in the Styles panel (at the bottom within sections called "Pseudo ::after element"), complete with the `display: none` declaration you just added.